# Meteor package: no such template

Tags: meteor, package

I'm writing an internal package in my Meteor app, and I cannot seem to get it to expose the packages templates to the rest of the app.

In my `package.js` file I have the following:

```js
api.use(['templating', 'spacebars', 'ui'], 'client');
api.addFiles([
  'client/templates/notifications/notifications.html',
  'client/templates/notifications/notifications.js',
  'notify.js',
  'lib/collections/notifications.js'
], 'client');
```

and in `notifications.html` I have

```html
<template name="notifications">
  ...
</template>
```

Back in the rest of the app, I have a `layout.html` template which simply uses the template like `{{> notifications}}`. But this causes the error:

`Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: No such template: notifications
    at Blaze.View.lookup (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2809:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:71:23)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1808:16
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2043:12)
    at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1807:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:296:36)
    at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:214:10)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:487:11)
    at Blaze.View.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1806:19)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:70:10)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually added the package to the app ? I know this is kinda silly but even if the package lives under the application `packages/` directory you still have to `meteor add` it.

Comment: @saimeunt that may actually be it... it's an internal package which I created with `meteor create --package` but I don't think I ever did a `meteor add`... Did not realize you had to explicitly add it even if it was directly in /packages.

Comment: @Paul the former: the file is inside `packages/name:space/client/templates/notifications` so I figured this was the correct way to add the file. I also do have additional code in my `package.js` file which exports an object for use in the rest of the app.

Comment: @saimeunt if you add that comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted as it has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without having a repo to reproduce, but here's an idea: [rubaxa:sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/tree/master/meteor) is a package I wrote that exposes a template successfully. Try to see what's different in yours.

BTW, you only need to api.use('templating'). No need for 'spacebars' and 'ui' just to expose a template. You may need additional functionality though.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment yet, I write here the answer from @saimeunt :

> Have you actually added the package to the app ? I know this is kinda
>   silly but even if the package lives under the application packages/
>   directory you still have to meteor add it.

Go in packages directory and run :

```
meteor add <YOUR_PACKAGE>
```

It solved the issue.

Thank you @saimeunt !